# Direction of a test subject

Tags: probability, limits, probability-distributions, random-variables

*In each test, a test subject may go left or right. In the first test go right with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ and go left with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. In the following tests, probability of going right only depends on what it happens in the previous test. In particular:*

*- if in the $(n-1)$ test the subject has gone right, in the $n$ test go right with probability $\mathbb{P}(D_{n}|D_{n-1})=0,6$;*

*- if in the $(n-1)$ test the subject has gone left, in the $n$ test go right with probability $\mathbb{P}(D_{n}|S_{n-1})=0,7$.*

***Find:***

1) *$\mathbb{P}(D_{2})$.*

2) *$\mathbb{P}(D_{n})~,~$ for a general $n$.*

3) *$\lim\limits_{n \to\infty}\mathbb{P}(D_{n}).$*

---

For 1) we have $\mathbb{P}(D_{2})=\mathbb{P}(D_{1})\mathbb{P}(D_{2}|D_{1})+\mathbb{P}(S_{1})\mathbb{P}(D_{2}|S_{1})=0,65$.

For 2) we have $\mathbb{P}(D_{n})=\mathbb{P}(D_{n-1})\mathbb{P}(D_{n}|D_{n-1})+\mathbb{P}(S_{n-1})\mathbb{P}(D_{n}|S_{n-1})$, and in all likelihood we have to apply the lack of memory $\mathbb{P}(X>k+h|X>k)=\mathbb{P}(X>k)$ but I don't understand how.

For 3), unfortunately, no idea.

Could you give me some suggestions? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the conditional split you mentioned:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(D_{n}) &= \mathbb{P}(D_{n-1})\color{blue}{\mathbb{P}(D_{n}|D_{n-1}) }+\mathbb{P}(S_{n-1})\color{magenta}{\mathbb{P}(D_{n}|S_{n-1})} \\
&=\mathbb{P}(D_{n-1})\color{blue}{\frac6{10} } + \bigl(1 - \mathbb{P}(D_{n-1}) \bigl) \color{magenta}{\frac7{10}} \qquad \because \mathbb{P}(S_{n-1}) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(D_{n-1}) \\
&= \frac7{10} - \frac1{10} \mathbb{P}(D_{n-1}) \\
\end{align}
Thus we have a recursion relation between any $\mathbb{P}(D_k)$ and $\mathbb{P}(D_{k-1})$. Plug in $\mathbb{P}(D_{n-1})$ given by $\mathbb{P}(D_{n-2})$ we can push one more level down, and so on.
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(D_n)&= \frac7{10} - \frac1{10} \left( \frac7{10} - \frac1{10} \mathbb{P}(D_{n-2}) \right) \\
&= \frac7{10} \left(1-\frac1{10} \right) \color{red}{\mathbf{\!{}+{}}} \frac1{100} \mathbb{P}(D_{n-2}) \\
&= \frac7{10} \left(1-\frac1{10} \right) + \frac1{100} \left( \frac7{10} - \frac1{10} \mathbb{P}(D_{n-3}) \right) \\
&= \frac7{10} \left(1-\frac1{10}+\frac1{100}\right) -\frac1{1000} \mathbb{P}(D_{n-3}) \\
&=~~\vdots \\
&= \frac7{10} \left(1-\frac1{10}+\frac1{100} - \cdots + \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{10^{k-1}}\right) +(-1)^k\frac1{10^k} \mathbb{P}(D_{n-k}) \\
&= \frac7{10} \frac{ 1 - (-1/10)^k}{1 - (-1/10)} +(-1)^k\frac1{10^k} \mathbb{P}(D_{n-k}) \\
&= \frac7{10} \frac{10}{11}\left( 1 - (\frac{-1}{10})^k \right) +(-1)^k\frac1{10^k} \mathbb{P}(D_{n-k}) \\
&=~~\vdots \qquad \text{take k = n-1}\\
&= \frac{7}{11}\left( 1 - \Bigl( \frac{-1}{10} \Bigr)^{n-1}\right) + \Bigl( \frac{-1}{10} \Bigr)^{n-1} \mathbb{P}(D_1) 
\end{align}
Given $\mathbb{P}(D_1) = 1/2$, this is the desired the general formula:
$$\mathbb{P}(D_n) = \frac{7}{11} - \frac3{22} \Bigl( \frac{-1}{10} \Bigr)^{n-1} \qquad \forall n \geq 2
$$

The first few terms are 
\begin{alignat}{2}
\mathbb{P}(D_1) &= \frac12 &&= 0.5 \\
\mathbb{P}(D_2) &= \frac{13}{20} &&= 0.65 \\
\mathbb{P}(D_3) &= \frac{127}{200} &&= 0.635\\
\mathbb{P}(D_4) &= \frac{1273}{2000} &&= 0.6365 \\
\mathbb{P}(D_5) &= \frac{12727}{20000} &&= 0.63635 \\
\mathbb{P}(D_6) &= \frac{127273}{200000} &&= 0.636365
\end{alignat}

It's easy to see that as $n$ gets larger, the oscillating power of $-1/10$ vanshies, and
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{P}(D_{n}) = \frac7{11} \approx 0.636363\overline{63}$$
with repeating digits $63$.